# probability question

Tags: probability, bayesian, self-study

I would like to calculate the following conditional probability:
I know that the probability of a BLUE ball being drawn is 0.3.
I receive a message from A or B who saw the ball that has been drawn.
This person tells me that the ball drawn is BLUE.
I know the probabilities:

A observing BLUE and sending BLUE- 0.16
B observing RED and sending BLUE - 0.09
A observing BLUE and sending BLUE- 0.05
B observing RED and sending BLUE- 0.17

I also know the probabilities:

A observing BLUE and sending RED - 0.019
B observing RED and sending RED- 0.323
A observing BLUE and sending RED-0.073
B observing RED and sending RED=0.106

I would like to calculate the conditional probability of the ball drawn actually being BLUE given that I received the message BLUE and the information I know about each player's probability of sending a given message.

Comment: your statement of the problem is vague. Please consider restating it more clearly.

Comment: @Daniel Hint: the situation determines four cases altogether: truth+yellow, etc.  Can you work out the chances where blue is involved?

Comment: @Daniel Please don't destroy your question only to ask a new variant of it.  Instead, you are able to edit your original question (this one) to reflect any improvements or changes you would like to make.

Comment: @Daniel That's a great improvement: well done.  However, it's difficult to decipher the last four lines.  What is "PRIOR"?  What do "d" and "h" represent?  Something seems to be missing in the last line.  What does "~0.45" mean?

Comment: @Daniel I'm struggling to make sense of this information.  To me, the first four assumptions imply the probability of somebody observing blue is 0.16 + 0.05 = 0.21, because (I presume) the two conditions are mutually exclusive (friends are not enemies) and exhaustive (one is either a friend or an enemy).  It therefore appears contradictory to assert that this probability equals 0.3.  Also missing from your account is any clear and full distinction between "observing" and "sending".  What is the error matrix for this channel?

Comment: @whuber to your previous comment: the probability of someone observing blue is different from the probability of the ball being drawn is blue given someone sending the message blue. Please look at the new modified version of the question above. The question is what is the probability that the ball drawn is BLUE given that I received the message BLUE and I know the probabilities with which the two players send RED or BLUE depending on what they observed.

Comment: @Daniel I'm sorry about being too busy to participate in a chat today.  As your question continues to be refined, I continue to think that the approach suggested by @Greg Snow is the right one: this is a standard (and simple) Bayesian calculation, a natural variant of the [binary symmetric channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_symmetric_channel) of coding theory.

Comment: @DBR If you would like the question removed, then simply flag it by following the "flag" link and explain the reason why.  If you continue damaging this thread, your access to this site will have to be suspended without any further warning.

Comment: @DBR In response to your flags: the replies are relevant to earlier versions of the question (which remain in the archive accessible to anyone) and appear to have helped resolve or clarify your question.  It has also has picked up some substantial trains of comments as well as a chat thread.  This site's moderators are reluctant to destroy all that or to make it incomprehensible by erasing your question.  If you are unhappy with how the question is specified, then by all means clarify it, but out of respect for the help others have provided, please don't eliminate it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

If Truth/Lie and color are independent and everything is random, then you would have an 18% chance of an honest person seeing blue and a 28% chance of a lier seeing yellow (and therefore claiming to see blue), you also have a 12% chance of lier seeing blue and 42% chance of honest seeing yellow.  So the probability of an honest person seeing blue given that the person claimed to see blue is $\frac{0.18}{0.18+0.28} = 0.39$.

Comment: Please read the [wiki for the homework tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info), especially the section on answering homework questions.

Comment: @Daniel, It's probably a good idea for you to comment on why you think this answer is right or wrong. Maybe, you could draw a picture?

Comment: @Daniel, Your last sentence in your original post reads..."I would like to know the probability of an honest person observing the blue colour given that he told me that the colour is blue." Should that say...."I would like to know the probability of an honest person observing the blue colour given that __I was told__ that the colour is blue". In other words, you don't know if the person telling you is honest or not.

Comment: @Daniel, If someone tells you the colour is blue, how many different ways/combinations can you interpret that information, given your original post?

Comment: @Daniel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/731/discussion-between-bill-080-and-daniel)

Comment: @Daniel I know, the site automatically creates that "exact duplicate label" after a merge.  That can't be helped.  But evidently your new question functions merely as a modification of this original one.   By continuing the conversation here, you respect the replies that were graciously offered by earlier respondents and you maintain a coherent record of how the question (and the replies) have been improved.  Obliterating your original question (and leaving the replies and the chat record behind) will only be confusing and destructive.

Answer (score 0):

If the honest person said "blue", and we are not dealing with the possibility of a misperception (honestly getting confused about colors), then there's a 100% chance it's blue.

But I suspect this isn't the question you intended to ask.